# Weird Spaces After PHP Generated HTML

Tags: php, internet-explorer, function, whitespace

I have a weird issue. I have a dynamic website [www.lamanscanada.com](http://www.lamanscanada.com/showers/defender) it appears fine in firefox and safari and almost perfect in IE7. But it appears that on certain php generated html. There is a bunch of space added after the function output. I also user mod_rewrite for nice SEO urls just a note.

The function sorts an array of data into columns with bullets

```
<?php
//breaks array values into two columns
function groupBullets($array){
   //count the array items
   $bulletcount = count($array);
   //divides that in two and round the result 
   $roundhalf = round(($bulletcount/2));
   //initailize a counting variable
   $i=1;
   //loop throught the array 
   foreach($array as $bullet){
       //if it is the first item 
       if($i==1){
           echo "<span class=\"container\">";//open the main container div
       }
       echo "<span class=\"bullet\">&bull;&nbsp;$bullet</span>";//then create bullet
       //if the counter is at the half mark
       if($i==$roundhalf){
           echo "</span>";//close the container
           $i=1;//and start the counter over
       }else{
           $i++;//if not at half keep counting
       }
   }
}
//end

//I am implementing it like this:
//this is my array it actually has a second level
$array = array(
        columngroup01("bullet 1","bullet 2","bullet 3","bullet 4"),
        columngroup02("bullet 1","bullet 2","bullet 3","bullet 4")
);

//I loop through this array
foreach($array as $column=>$arrayofbullets){
    echo "<div class=\"columncontainer\">".//open the div contains the columns
    "<div class=\"heading\">$column</div>";//print the title of the column
    //use the groupBullets function on each array of bullets
    groupBullets($arrayofbullets);
    echo "</div>";//close the column container
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you get this problem fixed or do you still want help regarding this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<span class="features">` is not being closed at the end of the generated list of `<span class="featureitem">` tags.

Current generated output:

```
<div class="infoblock">
    <div class="infoheading">features</div>
    <span class="features">
        <span class="featureitem">&bull;&nbsp;10'X6'X8' Aluminum Extrusion Structure</span>
        <span class="featureitem">&bull;&nbsp;R18 Insulated Panels</span>
        ...
</div>
```

Needs to be:

```
<div class="infoblock">
    <div class="infoheading">features</div>
    <span class="features">
        <span class="featureitem">&bull;&nbsp;10'X6'X8' Aluminum Extrusion Structure</span>
        <span class="featureitem">&bull;&nbsp;R18 Insulated Panels</span>
        ...
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow one of those things.... Sometimes all you need is a fresh set of eyes, Greatly appreciated.